# C - Parameterized Macros

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I can' figure out what is the advantage of using

```
#define CRANDOM() (random() / 2.33);
```

instead of

```
 float CRANDOM() {
    return random() / 2.33;
}
```

Comment: The macro gives you a `double`. And if you have a really poor compiler, it uses one function call less.

Comment: I wouldn't put the `;` in the macro...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth; Yet another reason why macros are bad practice; Because C programmers tend to write a semi-colon at the end of every line they write;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using a `#define macro` you are forcing the body of the macro to be inserted [inline](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html).

When using a function there will<sup>1</sup> be a function call (and therefor a jump to the address of the function (among other things)), which will slow down performance somewhat.

The former will most often be faster, even though the size of the executable will grow for each use of the #defined macro.

---

- [**greenend.org.uk - Inline Functions In C**](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html)

---

<sup>1</sup> *a compiler might be smart enough to optimize away the function call, and inline the function - effectively making it the same as using a macro. But for the sake of simplicitly we will disregard this in this post.*

Answer (score 3):

It makes sure that the call to `CRANDOM` is inlined, even if the compiler doesn't support inlining.

Comment: Which is far less important than it used to be, in these days of compilers that can outstrip most assembler programmers for optimisation :-) But that's probably still the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, that `#define` is incorrect due to the semi-colon at the end, and the compiler would baulk at:

```
float f = CRANDOM() * 2;
```

Secondly, I personally try and avoid using the preprocessor beyond separating platform-independent sections in cross-platform code, and of course code reserved exclusively for DEBUG or non-DEBUG builds.

nightcracker correctly states it will always be "effectively" inline, but given you can re-write the function to be `inline` itself, I see no advantage to using the preprocessor version *unless* the C-compiler in question does not inline.

Answer (score 1):

The former is old style. The only advantage of the former is that if you have a compiler following the old C90 standard, the macro will work as inlining. On a modern C compiler you should always write:

```
inline float CRANDOM() {
    return random() / 2.33f;
}
```

where the inline keyword is optional.

---

(Note that float literals must have a f at the end, otherwise you force the calculation to be performed on double, which you then implicitly round into a float.)

Comment: Most FPU's do all floating point calculations in double-precision anyway, unless the FPU is explicitly set to single-precision mode.

Comment: @nightcracker If there is even a FPU available, that is. The OP does not mention any specific platform.

Comment: @Lundin another note is that the keyword `inline` can be ignored by the compiler, it's just a way of telling it "I'd like you to inline this", but it can effectively do whatever it wants.

Comment: you probably want `static inline` - otherwise, you need to provide a second definition with external linkage in a different translation unit (C99 vs GNU inline semantics - see eg http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline )

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function involves a little bit of overhead -- pushing the return address onto the machine stack and branching, in this case.  By using a macro, you can avoid this overhead. A long time ago, this was important; these days, many compilers will insert the body of a tiny function like this inline, anyway. In general, trying to fool the compiler into emitting faster code is a fool's game; you often end up creating something slower.